# How to pass next page url with html in mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my project currently I have infinite scroll and getting listing from server side as html using MVC. I want to pass next page url with listing html so that when user reaches at the end java script can take next page url value and issue request to server for next listing. 
I have two idea for this.
1)use div tag at the end of page listing or at the last li of listing, set custom attribute value as next page url,and whenever needed get from div or li tag using id or class.
List.cshtml file contain

```
<li>.....</li>
<li>.....</li>
<li>.....</li>
.
.
<li>.....</li>
<div id="nextUrl" nextUrl="@Model.NextUrl">
```

And JS file contain

```
var path=$("#nextUrl").attr("nextUrl");
$.ajax({
       url: path,
       cache: false,
       success: function (html) { $("li:last").after(html); }
```

2)at the end of list use script tag and then declare variable(global) and assign next page url to it and get whenever needed.

List.cshtml contain

```
<li>.....</li>
<li>.....</li>
<li>.....</li>
.
.
<li>.....</li>
<script>path="@Model.NextUrl"</script>
```

JS file contain

```
  $.ajax({
       url: path,
       cache: false,
       success: function (html) { $("li:last").after(html); }
```

I don't know which is better or Is there any other way to solve it?(I also want next page url at page load)

Comment: Please share your code, till now whatever you tried...

Comment: Ah, the age old question of "should I store this in a hidden div or declare a global javascript variable?"  Technically the javascript variable is quicker (because you'd have to use jQuery to get the div and then get the value) but mostly this is a question of style.

Comment: You may use @Html.ActionLink()

Comment: All you need is a javascript containing the count of the current items (so that it can be passed to your controller method and used in a `.Skip()`/`.Take()` query.